# How do I get the size (width x height) of my pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a window using

```
pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), 
                        pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Later on in the app I want to be able to ask that window its width and height so I can decide how to process the mouse position.

How do I access the dimensions of that pygame window elsewhere in the program? (event processing loop)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want to get the surface, then get the size from the surface object.

Using tuple unpacking:

`w, h = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()`

Answer (score 8):

You can get the windows size by first getting the display surface. pygame.display.get_surface(), then calling get_width() / get_height() on the surface.

Answer (score 5):

Like this!

```
surface = pygame.display.get_surface() #get the surface of the current active display
x,y = size = surface.get_width(), surface.get_height()#create an array of surface.width and surface.height
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding another answer since I haven't seen this one yet.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode() # Default to screen resolution.

area = screen.get_rect()
```

We can call `get_rect()` on screen because it is a surface object. `area` will be a Rect object, with (0, 0, width, height) information in it.

Comment: Internet Points for using `pygame.Rect`, this structure is very useful in a PyGame environment.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pygame as pg
def create_window(width, height):
    """create a width x height resizable window/frame"""
    win = pg.display.set_mode((width, height), pg.RESIZABLE)
    # optional fill bg red, default is black
    win.fill((255, 0, 0))
    # optional title info
    sf = "size x=%s  y=%s" % (width, height)
    pg.display.set_caption(sf)

    # any extra code here ...
    # draw a white circle
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    # center can be fixed or calculated for resize
    center = (150, 150)
    radius = 100
    pg.draw.circle(win, white, center, radius)

    pg.display.flip()
    return win
pg.init()
width = 300
height = 200
win = create_window(width, height)
# event loop and exit conditions (windows titlebar x click)
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.VIDEORESIZE:
            width, height = event.size
            # redraw win in new size
            win = create_window(width, height)
            print(win.get_size())  # test
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
```

Try this out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using the opengl library, so I have discovered that adjusting the size messes up the opengl context somehow.  Eventually I'll dig around to figure out how I should cope with that.

Comment: So did the answer help?

Answer (score 2):

```
changed = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            scrsize = event.size  # or event.w, event.h
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(scrsize,RESIZABLE)
            changed = True
```

it's almost exactly like this in the comments for pygame.display.init doc page https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#comment_pygame_display_update
edited only slightly from 2011-01-25T23:10:35 - Dave Burton  thanks dave

Answer (score 2):

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

x=gameDisplay.get_width()

y=gameDisplay.get_height()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object associated with the display with [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface):

```py
window_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
```

Each *Surface* object can be asked for its with and height with [`get_width()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) respectively [`get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height):

```py
window_width = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()
window_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
```

[`get_size()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size) returns a tuple with the width and height of the window:

```py
window_width, window_height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
```

[`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle the size of the window, always starting at (0, 0):

This can be used to get the center of the display:

```py
window_center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center
```

It can even be used to limit the movement of an object to the window area:

```py
object_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

```py
object_rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

object_rect = pygame.Rect(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center, (0, 0)).inflate(30, 30)
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.key.name(event.key))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    object_rect.move_ip(
        (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel,
        (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel)
        
    object_rect.clamp_ip(pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect())

    pygame.display.get_surface().fill([64] * 3)
    pygame.draw.rect(pygame.display.get_surface(), (255, 0, 0), object_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```