# pygame cant stop the image from moving out of the screen when touching the bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am attempting to create a window where a sprite is stopped if it tries to go past the edges.

This has worked for all of the sides of the window except for the bottom.

this is the function:

```
 def barrier(self,width,height):
    if self.rect.right >= width:
        self.rect.right = width
    if self.rect.left <= 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
    if self.rect.bottom >= height:
        self.rect.bottom = height
    if self.rect.top <= 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
```

full code:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,xcor,ycor,width,height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (xcor,ycor))
        self.rand = random.randint(1,8)
    def randmovement(self,speed):
        x = random.randint(1,40)
        if x == 40:
            self.rand = random.randint(1,8)
        if self.rand == 1:
            self.rect.y -= speed
        if self.rand == 2:
            self.rect.y += speed
        if self.rand == 3:
            self.rect.x += speed
        if self.rand == 4:
            self.rect.x -= speed
    def barrier(self,wid,hght):
        if self.rect.right >= wid:
            self.rect.right = wid
        if self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= hght:
            self.rect.bottom = hght
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

pygame.init()

screenwidth = 1920
screenheight = 1080

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenheight))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

blockgroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

for _ in range(20):
    block = Block(screenwidth/2,screenheight/2,40,40)
    blockgroup.add(block)

while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for block in blockgroup.sprites():
        block.randmovement(3)
        block.barrier(screenwidth,screenheight)
    
    blockgroup.update()
    blockgroup.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I think its something to do with the sprite itself. it is a instance of the pygame.Surface() class and ive just put a rect around it, but i cant seem to understand why it failed only on the bottom of the pygame window. when running

```
print(self.rect.bottom)
```

It returns the expected value(the height of the screen).
It seems like the rect has moved to the correct position but the actual image has continued moving off the screen. The image has no transparent areas and is just a black rectangle.

EDIT: I found a solution, and it has to do with the size of the pygame window. I noticed that when making the main window smaller the barrier worked fine. when lowering the height value by around 200 the barrier seemed to work. Of course, I dont want to have a smaller window, so in the barrier() function I simply took 200 off of the height there.

The height of the screen is 1080, so setting the height value to 900 should fail of course. I assume that this MIGHT be a bug with pygame, not a bug from my code.

Comment: Do not repeat questions, but improve the original question.

Comment: Ist the size of the rectangle the size of the Sprite? Hast the image some large trasparent areas?

Comment: no, the image does not have any transparent areas. i would assume that it is the exact same size, because i used the get_rect() function.

Comment: The `get_rect()` does not clip the transparent areas. The rectangle has the size of the image not the size of the sprite in the image. Can you add the image to the question?

Comment: the image is a pygame.Surface

Comment: i dont have the picture downloaded. it was created using pygame.Surface((100,100)).

Comment: *" I assume that this might be a bug with pygame, not a bug from my code."* - Sorry, but no. It is a bug in your code. You messed up something.

Comment: whatever the issue is, the screenheight value that went into my function was somehow offset, despite the value being the exact same height as my screen, 1080 pixels.

Comment: Do you get the width and height of the window with `get_width()` and `get_height()`? Do you use a fullscreen window? (A fullscreen cannot have any size)

Comment: Yes it is a full screen window. the getwidth and getheight functions do not return an error but instead return a memory location for the window. Edit: they actually dont return memory locations. I tried to directly print the width and the height, but defining a variable as screen.get_height() and printing that returned the height and width. 1080 and 1920.

Comment: A fullscreen cannot have any size. When you use a fullscreen then the  size of the window is the best fitting fixed size (640x480, 800x600 ...). You have to get the size of the window with [`window.get_width()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_width) and [`window.get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height) (I don't know the name of your display surface, so I use `window`.

Comment: If you had provided the relevant part of your code, the problem would have been resolved in minutes.

Comment: *"the getwidth and getheight functions do not return an error "*  No they do not. You just used them wrongly. No one can help you since you don't show your code. See [How do I get the size (width x height) of my pygame window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653519/how-do-i-get-the-size-width-x-height-of-my-pygame-window)

Comment: Is the window larger than your screen?

Comment: No. i have a 1080p display. if the display was smaller then the pygame window then the other sides(left,right,top) of the screen would also fail.

Comment: What is you system? You appear to be the only one in the world with this problem. I cannot reproduce your issue. The program works fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,screenheight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)` followed by `screenwidth = screen.get_width()` `screenheight = screen.get_height()`

Comment: I run a linux system with Debian.

Comment: that worked, although the barrier at the bottom isnt perfectly aligned and a few pixels off.

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual width and height of the display from the display surface:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
screenwidth = screen.get_width() 
screenheight = screen.get_height()
```