# How can I resize terminal window from Python?

Tags: python, game-engine, python-2.x

I'm trying so hard and pushing myself to my limits, but I just can't figure  out how to resize  a terminal to my desire. Is there any way that someone can help me solve it? I would like the terminal to be solved with its unique code in different operating systems or you could just try to solve it in one or more lines of code.

```py
#!usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

### Requirements for default python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import generators

### Available for all python sources
from sys import platform
from os import system

class MainModule(object):
    def __init__(self, terminal_name, terminal_x, terminal_y):
        self.terminal_name = terminal_name
        self.terminal_x = terminal_x
        self.terminal_y = terminal_y

        if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
            # Code to resize a terminal for linux distros only
        if platform == "win32" or platform == "win64":
            # Code to resize a terminal for windows only
        if platform == "darwin":
            # Code to resize a terminal for mac only
```

Comment: look at the OS APIs and their documentations, that should help you (also `if platform in ('linux', 'linux2':)` and `if platform in ('win32', 'win64'):` is a bit shorter)

Comment: I would guess this is not possible,  certainly not reliably.  Certainly with Linux, 'terminal window' is ill-defined, what desktop manager am I running, am I running a desktop manager at all etc. etc.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is not generically possible, it's also a bad user experience.  I set up my terminal the way I want it.  I don't want your application to change my settings.  YOU need to adapt to what I'VE set up.  And, by the way, on Python 3 none of those `__future__` imports are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have discovered, the implementation is platform-specific. You'll have to write code to do this for each platform.

On Windows, there are [Windows APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) that can be used to do this. You can leverage Windows APIs directly using the `ctypes` module. One example of this can be seen in the [`PyGetWindow` package](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/blob/c5f3070324609e682d082ed53122a36002a3e293/src/pygetwindow/_pygetwindow_win.py#L249-L259). Other tools like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (via [`ahk` Python package](https://github.com/spyoungtech/ahk)), and [PyWinAuto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) are alternative tools to do this for Windows.

```py
# example using the AHK package on Windows
from ahk import AHK
ahk = AHK()
win = ahk.find_window(title=b'Untitled - Notepad')
win.move(x=200, y=300, width=500, height=800)
```

On MacOS, you can write an [apple script](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/mac-os-x/how-size-or-resize-application-windows-applescript/) to resize the window and launch `osascript` from a subprocess.

```py
# Using applescript on MacOS
import subprocess
APPLICATION_NAME = "Safari"
X = 300
Y = 30
WIDTH = 1200
HEIGHT = 900
APPLESCRIPT = f"""\
tell application "{APPLICATION_NAME}"
    set bounds of front window to {X}, {Y}, {WIDTH}, {HEIGHT}
end tell
"""

subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', APPLESCRIPT], capture_output=True)
```

For Linux, as Jeff mentions in the comments, the Linux implementation will depend on the window manager used of which [there are many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers). But for popular platforms like Ubuntu, you may rely on existing tools like the `wmctrl` package or similar packages.

```py
# ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/94866

import subprocess

WINDOW_TITLE = "Terminal"  # or substring of the window you want to resize
x = 0
y = 0
width = 100
height = 100

subprocess.run(["wmctrl", "-r", WINDOW_TITLE, "-e", f"0,{x},{y},{width},{height}"])
```

Though, if you are writing a game or similar, you can get around this a different way. For example, pygame lets you [set your window size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36653519/5747944) or in text-based terminal applications, `curses` (or a popular wrapper for curses, `blessings`) can be used to detect terminal size and you can resize your application dynamically, which may take some changing of your current code to do.

```py
height = curses.LINES
width = curses.COLS

redraw(width, height) # you implement this to change how your app writes to the terminal
```