# Pygame Display Width

Tags: python, pygame

I am using full screen for pygame, however I want to set some boundaries so that my player cannot escape the screen. I originally set boundaries like this:

```
if x > display_width - player_width or x < 0
    crash()
```

However, this will not work since there is not fixed display_width, is there some way that I can get a display width? Or can I use some other method to set boundaries on the screen.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653519/how-do-i-get-the-size-width-x-height-of-my-pygame-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Zulvex's answer, if you want to get the size of your monitor (instead of the fullscreen window) you can do

```
width, height = pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your looking for. It will provide the width and height, as a tuple.

```
width, height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
```

Credit: [How do I get the size (width x height) of my pygame window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653519/how-do-i-get-the-size-width-x-height-of-my-pygame-window)